# google loader causing browser to change location FF or blank page in chrome

Tags: google-ajax-api

I have an issue using the google loader in an existing webpages.

When I call e.g.

```
google.load("translate","1");
```

If FireFox, the browser changes it's location trying to load something from google which it never finishes and in Chrome the page just goes blank.

Has anyone experienced this before?

These pages are doing a lot of jquery, javascript and asp.net AJAX too. But I can't find anyting which seems to be causing it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue, after a while I found this solution.

http://markmail.org/message/vn57b44u7eqbrn3c

If you post your script I can probably provide more help

Comment: Thanks for the link. Passing a callback function to the load call worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Same issue, same solution as suggested by Allartk: adding the "callback" options to the load() call.
Here you can find detatailed and updated documentation:
[Google Loader API](https://developers.google.com/loader/)

Example:

```
function myCallback(){console.info("callback!");}    
google.load("translate","1","callback": myCallback);
```